# Loggers from LOG4J2 doesn't display every logs in console

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

Here is my log4j2.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<!--  
Fichier de configuration des loggers
@author theo.lalande
Hiérarchie des lvl:
ALL<TRACE<DEBUG<INFO<WARN<ERROR<FATAL<OFF
-->
<Configuration status="INFO" monitorInterval="30">
   <!-- PROPERTIES ______________________________________________________________________________ -->
   <Properties>
      <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
         %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${hostName} - [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
      </Property>
   </Properties>
   <!-- APPENDERS ______________________________________________________________________________ -->
   <Appenders>
      <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
         <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
         </PatternLayout>
      </Console>
      <!-- POUR TOUS LES LOGS -->
      <RollingFile name="FileAppenderAllLogs"
         fileName="logs/uService_all_logs.log"
         filePattern="logs/uService_all_logs-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
         <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
         </PatternLayout>
         <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
         </Policies>
         <DefaultRolloverStrategy
            max="7" />
      </RollingFile>
      <!-- POUR LES LOGS DE NIVEAU INFO -->
      <RollingFile name="FileAppenderInfoLogs"
         fileName="logs/uService_info_logs.log"
         filePattern="logs/uService_info_logs-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
         <Filters>
            <ThresholdFilter level="WARN" onMatch="DENY"
               onMismatch="ACCEPT" />
         </Filters>
         <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
         </PatternLayout>
         <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
         </Policies>
         <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="7" />
      </RollingFile>
      <!-- POUR LES LOGS DE NIVEAU WARN -->
      <RollingFile name="FileAppenderWarnLogs"
         fileName="logs/uService_warn_logs.log"
         filePattern="logs/uService_warn_logs-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
         <Filters>
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="DENY"
               onMismatch="ACCEPT" />
         </Filters>
         <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
         </PatternLayout>
         <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
         </Policies>
         <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="7" />
      </RollingFile>
      <!-- POUR LES LOGS DE NIVEAU ERROR -->
      <RollingFile name="FileAppenderErrorLogs"
         fileName="logs/uService_error_logs.log"
         filePattern="logs/uService_error_logs-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
         <ThresholdFilter
            level="FATAL" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT" />
         <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
         </PatternLayout>
         <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
         </Policies>
         <DefaultRolloverStrategy
            max="7" />
      </RollingFile>
      <!-- POUR LES LOGS DE NIVEAU FATAL -->
      <RollingFile name="FileAppenderFatalLogs"
         fileName="logs/uService_fatal_logs.log"
         filePattern="logs/uService_fatal_logs-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
         <ThresholdFilter
            level="OFF" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT" />
         <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
         </PatternLayout>
         <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
         </Policies>
         <DefaultRolloverStrategy
            max="7" />
      </RollingFile>
   </Appenders>
   <!-- LOGGERS ______________________________________________________________________________ -->
   <Loggers>
      <Root level="INFO" additivity="true">
         <priority value="INFO" />
         <AppenderRef ref="FileAppenderAllLogs" level="INFO" />
         <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="INFO" />

      </Root>
      <Logger name="com.compufirst.outstanding" level="INFO" additivity="false">
         <AppenderRef ref="FileAppenderInfoLogs" level="INFO" />
         <AppenderRef ref="FileAppenderWarnLogs" level="WARN" />
         <AppenderRef ref="FileAppenderErrorLogs" level="ERROR" />
         <AppenderRef ref="FileAppenderFatalLogs" level="FATAL" />
      </Logger>
   </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Every logs are split between different files according their level.
In the software entry point there are those logs :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;

@SpringBootApplication
public class OutstandingPoc1Application {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(OutstandingPoc1Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OutstandingPoc1Application.class, args);
        Configurator.setAllLevels(logger.getName(), Level.TRACE);

        logger.debug("Debugging log");
        logger.info("Info log");
        logger.warn("Hey, This is a warning1!");
        logger.error("Oops! We have an Error. OK");
        logger.fatal("Damn! Fatal error. Please fix me.");
    }
}
```

My problems are:

- The logs in the soft entry point never appears in uService_all_logs.log and only INFO and WARN level are written when i would like to have every logs (except debug and trace logs)
- Console never display logs from the entry point.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

No messages from the "com.compufirst.outstanding" logger or its children will appear on the console or `uService_all_logs.log`, because you set `additivity="false"` on the logger.

BTW: you can simplify your configuration greatly by using the [routing appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) to define per-level log files:

```xml
<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
</Console>
<RollingFile name="FileAppenderAllLogs"
             fileName="logs/uService_all_logs.log"
             filePattern="logs/uService_all_logs-%i.log">
    <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="7"/>
</RollingFile>
<Routing name="FileAppenderPerLevelLogs">
    <Routes pattern="$${event:Level}">
        <Route>
            <!-- Appender template -->
            <RollingFile name="FileAppender${event:Level}Logs"
                         fileName="logs/uService_${event:Level}_logs.log"
                         filePattern="logs/uService_${event:Level}_logs-%i.log">
                <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="7"/>
            </RollingFile>
        </Route>
    </Routes>
</RollingFile>

<Root level="INFO">
    <AppenderRef ref="FileAppenderAllLogs"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
</Root>
<Logger name="com.compufirst.outstanding">
    <AppenderRef ref="FileAppenderPerLevelLogs"/>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: Hi Piotr ! Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, setting additivity to True doesn't fix my problem. 
I'll look into routing appender, thanks for the tips!